# Set image src from web url in laravel 5.3 in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, path, laravel-5.3, src

I want to create some html element with bellow code in jquery in laravel 5.3:

```
 var LiService='<li id="Service'+serviceID+'"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ServiceModal'+serviceID+'" style="background-color: #e5e5e5;border-color: #0c0c0c; " class="list-group-item row">'+
                    '<div class="row"> <h4 class="col-md-9" style=" text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">'+nameService+'</h4>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="'+imagePath+'"> </div> </div> ';

 $("#ServicePanelUI").prepend(LiService);
```

variable `imagePath` is an url for image same : `"79.132.212.50/photo/111.JPG"`.

when i run code i see this code read image path from local host:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/SpecialGoruhKary/79.132.212.50/photo/111.JPG 404 (Not Found)
```

How must i write path ??

Comment: `//79.132.212.50/photo/111.JPG`